# Python - How to know which song is being played in media player (preferably VLC)

Tags: python, python-3.x, audio, vlc

I want to make a program for something and it requires knowing the name of the audio file being played currently in the media player. I will probably be using VLC media player.

How can I achieve that with Python?

Answer (score 2):

You're lucky that you want to use VLC, because you can access the data without anything hacky, such as, finding pointers in VLC process memory to figure out where the name of the song is stored. Instead we will do it the "hacky" way where will be no hacking, just stupid find title and extract the song name.

Open any song in VLC, and check what the title is.

It's `filename - VLC media player`, that's exactly what you need.

Normally I don't do this, but since this is very specific problem, and it's very hard to do when you don't know much about win32 API, I will provide an example on how it can be done.

Sadly, this is highly platform dependent, but here's a way to do it on windows (as I don't know how to do it on any other platform):

You'll need `ctypes` module.

```
import ctypes
from ctypes import c_int
from ctypes.wintypes import BOOL, HWND, LPARAM, LPWSTR


# You need to decorate function for callback
# to work, so I just put the decoration into another decorator
def win32_callback(callback):
    return ctypes.WINFUNCTYPE(BOOL, HWND, LPARAM)(callback)


# We need to tell ctypes what arguments must be passed to actual win32 functions that we will be using
def init_user32():
    user32 = ctypes.windll.user32
    user32.EnumWindows.argtypes = [ctypes.WINFUNCTYPE(BOOL, HWND, LPARAM), LPARAM]
    user32.GetWindowTextLengthW.argtypes = [HWND]
    user32.GetWindowTextW.argtypes = [HWND, LPWSTR, c_int]
    return user32


user32 = init_user32()


# Now, the actual logic:
@win32_callback 
def find_vlc_title(hwnd, lParam):
    length = user32.GetWindowTextLengthW(hwnd) + 1
    buff = ctypes.create_unicode_buffer(length)
    user32.GetWindowTextW(hwnd, buff, length)
    title = buff.value
    if "VLC" in title:
        print("vlc window title:", title)
        title_without_vlc = "-".join(title.split("-")[:-1])
        print("Remove vlc tag:", title_without_vlc)
        title_without_ext = ".".join(title.split(".")[:-1])
        print("Finally display actual song name without extension:", title_without_ext)
        # pass title_without_ext into a function, object or whatever you want there, win32 API isn't python friendly, and you can't just return it
        return False # Enumeration stops when we return False
    return True # keep Enumerating otherwise


if __name__ == "__main__":
    user32.EnumWindows(find_vlc_title, 0)
```

A lot of things are Windows specific and to understand them you need to learn to work with Win32 API, and only you can do that, if you want.

This is very hacky, and isn't guaranteed to work anywhere but on windows, where VLC shows name of file it has opened and it's own "VLC" tag at the end of it.

I opened VLC and played a random song, this is what I get:

```
$ python title.py
vlc window title: ParagonX9 - Blue Sky.mp3 - VLC leistuvė
Remove vlc tag: ParagonX9 - Blue Sky.mp3
Finally display actual song name without extension: ParagonX9 - Blue Sky
```

Have fun learning API of other platforms if you still want to do this...

Comment: It is giving me a NameError

`user32.EnumWindows.argtypes = [WND_ENUM_PROC, LPARAM]`

`NameError: name 'WND_ENUM_PROC' is not defined`

Comment: Yeah, my bad, `WND_ENUM_PROC` should just be the same thing as decorator for callback, I removed it but didn't update the code. Now it's fixed.

Comment: Sorry again, but it gives a Type Error now 
`user32.EnumWindows.argtypes = [win32_callback, LPARAM] 

TypeError: item 1 in _argtypes_ has no from_param method`

Comment: Works perfectly. Is there way to listen to signals from vlc to detect if a song has changed? Trying to create a program that can detect if a song has changed in real time and print out new song name. Or is it efficient enough t just some continuous loop code?